# Hibernate связывание сущностей по конкретному полю

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Я хочу связать две сущности связью многие к одному, но так, чтобы в классе сущности "многие" не хранилась ссылка на объект класса "один".

В общем, я хочу примерно вот такое:

```
@Entity(name = "A")
@Table(name = "As")
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}

@Entity(name = "B")
@Table(name = "Bs")
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_id", referencedColumnName = "A_id")
    private long owner;
}
```

Тут вместо объекта `A` хранится значение его `id` в поле `owner`.

Однако, при попытке использования такого кода (`session.save(objectB);`), я получаю исключения из серии `Error accessing field`.

Все геттеры-сеттеры есть.

Ну и вопрос: Как можно связать два класса только по одному полю, чтобы не было таких вот проблем?

*P.S. Мне нужно именно*

```
private long owner;
```

*а не*

```
private A owner;
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто по полю связывать нельзя, должна  быть еще таблица. Это достигается с помощью аннотации `@JoinTable` в классе B:

```
@OneToMany
JoinTable(name="AB", @JoinColumn(name="a_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="b_id")
private List<A> owner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - не обозначать связь в принципе. Указать ее только на уровне бд, а в программе обозначить как обычную колонку с форматом `long`.